Vowpal wabbit training contextual bandits on data with best arm
Let's say my data contains the best arm as a feature.
from vowpalwabbit import pyvw
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
context = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(100,))
np.random.seed(45)
arms = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(100,))

vw = pyvw.vw("--cb 10 --quiet -q :: --random_seed 123")

def build_example(action, cost, prob, features):
    return f"{action}:{cost}:{prob} | arm:{features}"

with open("data.txt", 'w') as file:   
    for ind in range(len(context)):
        action = arms[ind]
        # cost is 0 when vw predict arm from data
        cost= abs(action - context[ind])
        example = build_example(action, cost, 0.1, context[ind])
        # 3:3:0.1 | arm:6
        file.write(example + "\n")
        vw.learn(example)
vw.finish()

But when I try to predict the model always throws a 10 arm.
>>>vw.predict('| arm:4')
10

Also I try with command line:
vw --cb 10 -q :: --random_seed 123 -d data.txt -f model.vw

then copy | arm:4 to test.txt and run:
vw -d text.txt -i model.vw -p predictions.txt

In this case I alway get 9 arm.
So I'm confused by the result. Can anyone give me an explanation why the model is not trained in my example and why the prediction is different for the python interface and for the command line? Can vw learn to take the best hand from the given data?
